# Text editor that updates file without prompting

Tags: text-editor

Is there any console- or window-based text editor that automatically reloads file changed on disk without prompting anything?

Answer (score 2):

`vim` can do that. Just add

```
set autoread
```

to your `~/.vimrc`. (Also check out the [Tail Bundle plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1714).)
The `autoread` setting applies only certain events (which can be determined by checking the help text for `timestamp` (`:h timestamp`)). To make `vim` load files more frequently, there are two decent options:

1. [Define a function which watches for changes.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Have_Vim_check_automatically_if_the_file_has_changed_externally)
2. Set an autocommand such as:

   ```
   au FocusGained,BufEnter,BufWinEnter,CursorHold,CursorMoved * :checktime
   ```

   This will reload whenever `vim` gains focus, you enter the buffer, move a cursor, idle the cursor. It won't change the current cursor position though.

`emacs` can also do this, if you add to your `.emacs`:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode t)
```

This doesn't watch for changes either, but the following should:

```
(global-auto-revert-tail-mode t)
```

This is supposed to work like `tail -f`, according to the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoRevertMode).

Even if `gedit` doesn't support this, I'm sure there are plenty of other GUI editors which do.

Sources:

1. [Can vim monitor realtime changes to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157914/can-vim-monitor-realtime-changes-to-a-file)
2. [How to have Emacs auto-refresh all buffers when files have changed on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480572/how-to-have-emacs-auto-refresh-all-buffers-when-files-have-changed-on-disk)

Comment: Dear @muru, I am using Ubuntu 14.04. `set autoread` did not work. I have installed TailBundle but vim did not autoload the file. I do not know why. Should I write a command in vim? emacs works perfectly but there is an annoying period of waiting for the file to be updated. Is this waiting period related with a parameter (file check interval parameter, etc.)?

Comment: I am using vim, not vim-tiny. I have added `set nocompatible`, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Kadir I have updated the answer with a few more options.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs can do that for you. It is called `revert-buffer` in Emacs. If you want to enable it for every file that you open in Emacs, add the following to your `~/.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
 (global-auto-revert-mode 1)
```

See the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RevertBuffer) for more information. [This Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1735237) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For those who like something more modern, [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) does this by default.

```
// Always prompt before reloading a file, even if the file hasn't been
// modified. The default behavior is to automatically reload a file if it
// hasn't been edited. If a file has unsaved changes, a prompt will always
// be shown.
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

g/vim can do this when using this command:

```
:set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("lh")
```

(To scroll down automatically use ...`feedkeys("G")` instead (but it scrolls down every visible buffer, even when split)

... you can find explanation and additional information in this stackoverflow question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296697/4940240