# Text file viewer that automatically refreshes when file changes?

Tags: software-recommendation, text

I have a text-file that is being continually written to by another program.
`gedit` can refresh the text file contents by going to File -> Revert, but this requires manual input. Is there a text-file viewer (doesn't have to be GUI, a terminal viewer works fine) that automatically updates the contents of the file without manual input?

Comment: To my knowledge, such a thing does not exist unless you count `less +F <filename>` which automatically load data in real time that has been added to the file. Line changes are a different beast altogether, though. It's a great idea, and I see basically this exact same question come up fairly regularly, but I have yet to see a satisfactory answer to it.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/q/516115/158442

Comment: How does your text-file change? With new content append to it or changed somewhere in the content?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin For my particular scenario you can assume that new content is appended to it continually, without modifying the content that was already there before. Although it would be nice to have a text viewer that saw any type of change on the file, but I can see how that can be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `text-file` grows with new content append to it, you could use `tail` to track changes.

It could be achieved with `tail -f text-file` or `tailf text-file`

If you want to print the content in it from very beginning (or from certain line):

`tail -n +1 -f text-file`

"-n +1" for starting from the first line of it, more detailed explaination could be found in  `man tail`:

> -n, --lines=K
>           output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth